# highcart.js pointInterval for 15 days datetime x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want the time interval to be half month for x-axis. I figured out I can use pointInterval, but I am not sure why it doesn't work as expected

http://jsfiddle.net/nizsu/otatsrbq/

I expect the x-axis value to be: Aug 26, Sep 11, Sep 26

html

```
 <div class="module" id="changelist">
            <div id="chart1" style="min-width: 90%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart1').highcharts({       
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            pointInterval: 13 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, //half month interval
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, 7, 26),
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                month: '%b %e',
                year: '%b'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'New Visits',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 26), 50],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 27), 60],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 28), 65],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 29), 70],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 30), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 31), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 1), 75],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 2), 80],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 3), 85],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 4), 77],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 5), 70],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 6), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 7), 17],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 8), 80],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 9), 75],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 10), 73],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 11), 78],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 12), 82],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 13), 15],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 14), 18],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 15), 65],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 16), 70],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 17), 67],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 18), 73],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 19), 80],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 20), 17],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 21), 22],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 22), 65],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 23), 63],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 24), 68],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 25), 65],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 26), 70]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Total Visits',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 26), 75],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 27), 78],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 28), 80],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 29), 85],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 30), 35],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 7, 31), 30],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 1), 90],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 2), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 3), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 4), 97],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 5), 93],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 6), 30],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 7), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 8), 90],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 9), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 10), 93],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 11), 99],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 12), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 13), 35],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 14), 30],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 15), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 16), 94],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 17), 92],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 18), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 19), 100],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 20), 30],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 21), 33],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 22), 95],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 23), 91],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 24), 90],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 25), 94],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 8, 26), 95]
            ]
        }]
    });     
    });
```

Comment: If you need half a motnh (15 days) why you set 13 ?

Answer (score 1):

The setting you want is tickInterval, not point interval. You also need to specify startOnTick: true to make it start on your first point.

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 13 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, //half month interval
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, 7, 26),
        startOnTick: true,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
            month: '%b %e',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdy4deew/